# Timer and serial port in c#?

Tags: c#, timer, hardware

I am using an RFID device to read the data from it. After receiving the data from it I am using it in Visual Studio 2008. I use data-receive event of serial port and timer to get data.

The problem is when I get the RFID data and try to put it in a text field on the data receive event.

Continuously getting data because timer is continuously checking the data and putting this in text box. That's why my back end query is always running and inserting the same data continuously. I want to stop the timer and serial port and then want to open the serial again without closing and opening the form again. Is there any other way to get the data from serial port except timer, and after getting data it stop itself..

Here is my code:

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //Serialtimer.Start(); 
    if (sp.IsOpen) 
    { 
        data = sp.ReadExisting(); 
        RFIDtB.Text = data; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Please Check the device"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what a huge one sentence problem :) Cant you just use `DataReceived` event and `Close` method? Why do you need timer? Show some code please

Comment: private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
//Serialtimer.Start();
if (sp.IsOpen)
{

data = sp.ReadExisting();
RFIDtB.Text = data;
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Please Check the device");
}

}

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'RFIDtB' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
It gives error like this

Comment: Next time edit question and add code in it, not in comments. Also I cant see any timer here.

Comment: private void Serialtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
RFIDtB.Text = data;
}

Comment: I already wrote - edit question and put code there!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access form controls from other threads than the UI thread. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx for the solution.